# Topological group mod out by a finite group and compactness

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ be a finite subgroup of $G$. Assume further that $G$ is $T_1$ (this ensures $H$ is closed in $G$ and thus $G/H$ is again $T_1$) and $C_2$. If the coset space $G/H$ is compact, is $G$ also compact?

I believe I can show by the openness of $p:G\to G/H$ that if $G$ is furthermore Hausdorff then $G/H$ is compact then $G$ is compact. Just take any sequence $\{x_n \}$ in $G$, the image $\{p(x_n)\}$ in $G/H$ should have a converging subsequence. WLOG, assume $\{p(x_n)\}$ is convergent in $G/H$ to $\bar{y}$. $\bar{y}$ can be lifted to $y_1,\dots, y_h$ where $h$ is the order of $H$. If $G$ is furthermore Hausdorff (plus $C_2$), then we can separate them by nested neighborhood bases $\{ U_{1i} \}_i, \dots, \{U_{hi} \}_i$ (any $U_{pi}$ and $U_{qj}$ are disjoint if $p\ne q$. Each group can be mapped by $p$ to a nested neighborbood of $\bar{y}$) and each $\{x_n\}$ has to fall in one of them. By Pigeon Hole principle, we can select a converging subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ in one of those $h$ nested neighborhoods converging to some $y_i$. Please let me know if my argument is wrong.

Now instead of being Hausdorff, $G$ is just $T_1$ (and $C_2$). I feel like the argument above might not work. So is it still true in this case that $G$ is compact when $G/H$ is?

Comment: A topological group is Hausdorff iff it is $T_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! Do you think my argument above is correct? Or do you have some better approaches?

Comment: $C_2$ is newspeak for "second countable", isn't it? Then yes, the argument works. But second countability is rather restrictive. Since $H$ is finite, $p$ is a finitely-sheeted covering map. That gives you compactness of $G$ without assumptions about first or second countability.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! But how does the argument work by covering maps? I have thought about it. Say if $U_i$ is an arbitrary open cover for $G$ and $p(U_i)$ form an open cover of $G/H$ and thus have a finite subcover, say $p(U_1),\dots, p(U_n)$. Lifting those $n$ sets to $G$ gives us $nh$ many sets. But how to use those $nh$ many open sets to reduce $U_i$ to a finite cover? Those $nh$ sets might intersect infinitely many $U_i$

Comment: You take a finer cover of the base. Let $\pi \colon E \to B$ be a finitely-sheeted covering, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $E$. Then every point $x \in B$ has an open neighbourhood $V$ such that each sheet of $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is contained in an element of $\mathscr{U}$. I think you can finish the argument from here. If not, ask.